# How to Pass multiple Input and Output test file names dynamically In Junit 5?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I need to pass multiple files one by one to the below BeforeAll method. I can able to achieve it with different test classes of duplication of same code. I would like to optimize it using single class.

```
@BeforeAll
static void setUp() throws IOException {
    inputList = readInput(CommonTestConstants.FilePath + "/Input1.json");
    expectedList = readExpected(CommonTestConstants.FilePath + "/Expected1.json");
    assertEquals("Checking size of both list", inputList.size(), expectedList.size());
}

static Stream<Arguments> Arguments() {
    return IntStream.range(0, inputList.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> Arguments.of(inputList.get(i), expectedList.get(i)));
}

@ParameterizedTest
@DisplayName("Parameterized Test For First Input")
@MethodSource("Arguments")
void testFact(Object object, ExpectedObject expected) throws Exception {
    Outcome outcome = processExpectedJson(object);
    assertEquals(expected, outcome);
}
```

Any one please advise to achieve this?

Reference
[How to pass a Input and Expected file name dynamically for BeforeAll Method | Junit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750412/how-to-pass-a-input-and-expected-file-name-dynamically-for-beforeall-method-ju)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Map` of file names and then iterate iver it as below,

```
Map<String, String> files = Map.of("/Input1.json", "/Expected1.json",
                                    "Input1.json", "/Expected2.json");

files.forEach((k,v)->{
    inputList = readInput(CommonTestConstants.FilePath + k);
    expectedList = readExpected(CommonTestConstants.FilePath + v);
    assertEquals("Checking size of both list",
            inputList.size(), expectedList.size());
});
```